# Visual Studio assumes return value from FirstOrDefaultAsync() cannot be null

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq, .net-core, nullable-reference-types

I have the following query.

```
var railcarInfo = await (from rt in DbContext.RailcarTrips
                         where rt.WaybillRailcar.RailcarNumber == clm.RailcarNumber &&
                         rt.WaybillRailcar.Waybill.CreateDate <= clm.SightingDate
                         orderby rt.WaybillRailcar.Waybill.CreateDate descending
                         select new
                         {
                             RailcarTrip = rt,
                             WaybillCreateDate = rt.WaybillRailcar.Waybill.CreateDate,
                             IsLoaded = rt.WaybillRailcar.Weight > 0
                         })
                         .AsNoTracking()
                         .FirstOrDefaultAsync();
```

But for some reason, Visual Studio decides that *'railcarInfo' is not null here* immediately following this query.

[image]

The point of `FirstOrDefaultAsync()` is that it returns the first item in a collection, or null if the collection is empty. It could definitely be null here. Can anyone see why Visual Studio seems to get confused here?

Comment: @Evk nice find, if it had just clicked into the definition.... Anyway, this is likely worthy of an answer, you have all the available upvotes I am legally allowed to bestow

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As mentioned in [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/miscellaneous/nullable-reference-types) about this feature and EF:

> Prior to EF Core 6.0, the public API surface wasn't annotated for
> nullability (the public API was "null-oblivious"), making it sometimes
> awkward to use when the NRT feature is turned on. This notably
> includes the async LINQ operators exposed by EF Core, such as
> FirstOrDefaultAsync. The public API is fully annotated for nullability
> starting with EF Core 6.0.

So you likely using version of EF < 6.0